# How to change the polygon to achieve separation in a state in datamap?

Tags: d3.js, svg, maps, polygon, datamaps

How can I achieve the division of the California state using the coordinates in the datamapjs?

Below is the code change i have made in the datamap-js file.

```
{ "type": "Polygon", "id": "NCAL", "arcs": [[55, -47,55, 56, 57]], "properties": { "name": "Northern California" } },
            { "type": "Polygon", "id": "SCAL", "arcs": [[55,-57,55, 56, 57]], "properties": { "name": "Southern California" } },
```

**This is what I want to achieve.**

[image]

Comment: http://fiddle.jshell.net/8J9mG/143/

above fiddler include the datamap js file, I'm referring to. The separation of "California State" in to two (Sourthern and Northern)

Comment: @RobertLongson: I have added an example map together with the change i made to the js code.

Comment: Are you asking how to swap in your polygons?  Or are you asking how to figure out the polygon arc values?

Comment: I'm asking about the arc values.

Comment: Hi @Mark,
Any thoughts on the matter? Thanks in advance.

Comment: If I understand topo-json correctly, the `arc` values in your snippet above are indexes into the `arcs` array provided by datamaps as `Datamap.prototype.usaTopo.arcs`.  Essentially you are asking "how do I come up with new arcs to add to that array to split california"?  I would attempt to take the existing ones used to draw the left and right borders and split the arc array into two.  For the center line, you'll need to have come up with your own arc array but it should be doable since you'll know the coordinates of where you split the others.  It won't be easy.

Comment: Thanks @Mark, for your valuable comments. I'll try the approach you suggested.